# Grub Menu redundancy

Tags: grub2, wubi

Recently I installed Ubuntu using Wubi on my desktop. I already had Windows XP and Linux Mint in dual-boot, with the Grub Menu presenting the entries for both OS. Now that I've installed Ubuntu using Wubi, the original Grub Menu is intact, which was expected, because Wubi makes an entry on Windows boot menu. So I choose Windows XP from the original Grub Menu, then it displays the Windows boot menu, featuring Windows XP and Ubuntu. If I choose Windows XP, Windows is loaded, however if I choose Ubuntu, yet another Grub Menu comes up, with all three options there - Windows XP, Linux Mint and Ubuntu.

This is a bit unnecessary and redundant. Originally, I was expecting to have the original Grub and then Windows Boot Menu, now that there is a second Grub, I am afraid I might have some boot problem when I uninstall Ubuntu from Windows. How should I proceed to keep only one of the Grub menus, without compromising the possibility to boot into any of the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the wubi install: `sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`. Then `sudo update-grub`

I'm surprised that Windows XP appears on the Wubi grub menu - it's supposed to be suppressed (maybe that's only for Vista/7). But in any case, if you disable 30_os-prober it won't find any other operating systems and will suppress the grub menu by default.

Uninstalling Wubi will have no effect on your existing linux install (and it's grub setup).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I am now checking whether Ubuntu runs smoothly on my specs, if so, I'll do a proper installation on hard disk later and much likely delete the Wubi installion, thus my doubts about messing with the Grub menus.